# Best way to avoid many queries in one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates, one-to-many

I have a table of articles with contains id,title among others.

I have another table which contains all the images for each articles called imagePath which stores the path for images. It contains id,path,articleId among others.

Each article can have many images.

I want to get article and its associated images in the best way possible.

Option 1:

```
SELECT a.id,a.title,b.path 
FROM articles a, imagepaths b
WHERE a.id=b.articleId 
LIMIT 10;
```

Problem: This gives duplicate results. Article rows are duplicated for each image in imagepath

Option 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM imagepath 
WHERE articleId='111111'
```

But this has to be done for each image. I have pages which shows article abstracts for hundreds of articles. Assuming 100 articles with 2 images each this would take 1 call to article table and 200 calls to imagepath table.

How would you do this?

**Update****

How about using GROUP_CONCAT() like this:

```
select a.id,a.title,GROUP_CONCAT(b.imagePath) from articles a
inner join imagePaths b on a.id=b.unique_id
group by a.id limit 3
```

Result:

```
id  |     title |   GROUP_CONCAT(b.imagePath)

1   |   'title1'    |   path1,path2
2   |   'title2'    |   path3,path4,path5
3   |   'title3'    |   path6
```

this gives all the info I need. But the query takes 0.25s. I bit slow considering I might have to run many queries.

Is the best we can do?

Comment: Many optimized cacheable queries is better than one slow bigger query.

Comment: Are you sure that this is really a problem? The first rule of optimisation is that you don't know why your app is slow. I'd choose the option I though was best, write the code, and then if performance were an issue afterward I'd use profiling to determine how to speed things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 doesn't give you duplicate results - only if you already have duplicate data in the tables. It gives you more than one b.path for each a.title, but thats about it.

For example:

```
 articles:            imagepaths:

 ID | Title           articleId | Path
 ---+--------         ----------+-------------
  1 | Title1                 1  | /path1/
  2 | Title2                 1  | /path2/
                             2  | /path3/
                             2  | /path4/
```

...will give you this result:

```
 ID | Title  | Path
 ---+--------+------
  1 | Title1 | /path1/
  1 | Title1 | /path2/
  2 | Title2 | /path3/
  2 | Title2 | /path4/
```

Option 1 is in most cases the way I would do it. I'd reformat the query this way:

```
 SELECT a.id, a.title, b.path 
 FROM articles a
 INNER JOIN imagepaths b ON a.id = b.articleId
 LIMIT 10;
```

**Update:**

Ofc you can group it by Id:

```
 SELECT a.id, a.title, b.path 
 FROM articles a
 INNER JOIN imagepaths b ON a.id = b.articleId
 GROUP BY a.id;
```

But then your result will look like this:

```
 ID | Title  | Path
 ---+--------+------
  1 | Title1 | /path1/
  2 | Title2 | /path3/
```

If this is what you want... just do it! ;-)

Comment: Thanks Bjoern. 

This is exactly what I am getting.

 ID | Title  | Path
 ---+--------+------
  1 | Title1 | /path1/
  1 | Title1 | /path2/
  2 | Title2 | /path3/
  2 | Title2 | /path4/

Comment: cont...

Any way to avoid duplicate ID and Title in the result. Article table also contains many other columns and when I run this query all those 8 columns are beign returned twice, only the last column for path changes.

Can I avoid getting 2 rows for 1 ID?

Comment: Ok, this update makes it clear what you want. If you have trouble with your queries performance, try profiling it. There are many possibilities where there could be a bottlenecks. Check your indexes, database connection etc.